# How to use link_to_if with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, view-helpers

I'm trying to figure out how to write in HAML the use of [link_to_if](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/) helper with a do block.

I tried this one but it generate an error :

```
= link_to_if(test, my_text, my_path) do
  - some_other_text
```

Error : `syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' end;_hamlout.buffer << _hamlout.f...`

I know I could reach the same result with a `if else` statement and `link_to` helper, but I'd like to understand how to do it with link_to_if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (tested):

```
= link_to_if(test, my_text, my_path) do
  = some_other_text # this is a variable holding text
```

In HAML `=` means: print the result of the evaluated code, `-` means: evaluate the following code.

If this does not fix your problem you probably have an error somewhere else in your code when one of the variables used get evaluated.